# Is there a more efficient solution for importing KDB data into DolphinDB?

Tags: database, kdb, dolphindb

Like the question, is there a more efficient solution for importing KDB data into DolphinDB? I want to try dolphindb recently, but my data is so large and I want to use a efficient way to import data. I am actually not very sure what is recommended in dolphindb.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method:

(1) Export KDB data to csv file

(2) Use loadTextEx function to cooperate with task concurrency to efficiently import csv files into DolphinDB in multiple threads